# Android ICS unlock mechanism source code

Tags: android, menu, navigation, swipe

I'm developing an information application and I'd like to brighten it by using an interesting navigation just like Ice Cream Sandwitch unlock screen you can see below:

[image]

Swiping an object to one of four predefined locations starts an Activity. Nothing more :)

So maybe you have any sources or just an advice what to start from to create such menu?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [the GlowPadView library](http://www.androidviews.net/2012/11/glowpadview-lockring/), extracted from the Android open source project.